# On video.js Is it possible to pre-load a video while you have an existing video playing (without having two video.js instances)

Tags: javascript, video.js

We are using video.js to play through a playlist of videos in a continuous fashion. Sometimes the buffering time between the next ad or video can be quite long when a video ends and the next one begins. Is it possible to prebuffer/preload the next video while the existing one plays. One idea would be to use a separate video player and swap back and forth between but that seems quite complex. Is there any way to do this without having two instances (or is their a plugin that makes managing two video.js instances seamless?)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?